# Usar variables como $scope o $timeout en el constructor en Ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2, ionic-framework

Soy nuevo en Ionic y estoy intentando hacer uso del plugin de [background](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode/), tengo el siguiente simple y funcional constructor de mi aplicación:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode';
import { TabsPage } from '../pages/tabs/tabs';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = TabsPage;


  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private backgroundMode: BackgroundMode) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();

      // Configuracion de background 
      this.backgroundMode.enable();
    });
  }
}
```

Funciona joya! Ahora, quiero agregar la siguiente línea debajo de `this.backgroundMode.enable();`:

```
$timeout(function() {
    this.backgroundMode.moveToBackground();
}, 500);
```

El problema es que no sé como importar `$timeout`, al igual que `$scope`, que son variables que con controladores se pasan automaticamente, pero acá no tengo idea de como importarlas o declararlas. Probé agregandolas como parámetro del constructor, pero no funcionó.

Desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Puedes importar

```
import {TimerWrapper} from '@angular/core/src/facade/async';
```

Y utilizarlo :

```
TimerWrapper.setTimeout(() => {  
 this.backgroundMode.moveToBackground();
}, 3000);
```

O como propones tu ya que cambia la sintaxis

```
setTimeout(() => {  
 this.backgroundMode.moveToBackground();
}, 3000);
```

Comment: Gracias! Ahi acabo de solucionarlo, al parece es problema de sintaxis con el tema del cambio de versiones de Angular. Podrías agregar esto a tu respuesta: setTimeout(() => {
            this.backgroundMode.moveToForeground();
          }, 3000); 
Por si a alguien le sirve!

Comment: Excelente! Recuerda marcarla como correcta si soluciono tu problema :)

Comment: Ahí la marqué! Cuando puedas agrega esa parte si quieres!

Comment: Hola! Disculpame que te moleste! Veo que borraste lo que habías puesto como solución. La solución que yo plantié es diferente a la tuya, no tiene nada que ver con `TimerWrapper`, lo que yo proponía era que pongas **ambas** soluciones, la que habías puesto vos con TimerWrapper y la mía con `setTimeout` (que no necesita de TimerWrapper para funcionar). Porque sino parece que depende una de otra y nada que ver! jajaja Saludos! Y disculpame las molestias

Comment: Ahi lo arregle que lo hice desde el celular jajaja! @Genarito gracias por la aclaracion!